# Sort used time into specific time

Tags: r

I am trying to do analytics on a small office network, but I am having some problem trying to sort them into specific time.

I only know using:

```
result<-with(df,table(Source,DateTime))
```

but I am not sure how to sort them according to the specific time.

```
DateTime class [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

Df 
Source   |Protocol |DateTime 
10.0.0.6    SSDP    2014-08-14 15:52:03 
10.0.0.6    SSDP    2014-08-14 15:52:03  
10.0.0.10   SSDP    2014-08-14 15:52:04 
10.0.0.11   TCP     2014-08-14 15:52:21 
10.0.0.11   TCP     2014-08-14 20:52:21 
10.0.0.19   HTTP    2014-08-14 01:52:21
```

So, if the `Source` uses the `Protocol` at the `Time` convert them into `1`. If it doesn't use it convert it to `0`. Date doesn't really matter

```
result 
          06:00-19:59 |20:00-23:59 | 00:00-06:00 
10.0.0.6         1         0                  0 
10.0.0.10        1         0                  0 
10.0.0.11        1         1                  0 
10.0.0.19        0         0                  1
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to skip 18:00-21:59?

Comment: oops! sorry, re-edited. @hrbrmstr thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Yes! @akrun. I've tried gsub away the date but it will make it to string

Comment: @akrun tried it. Doesn't remove the date still

Comment: @akrun oh using cut function? i'll try first .

Comment: @akrun okay thnks i'll try to learn cut first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut` and `table` make quick work of this:

```
dat$bucket <- cut(as.numeric(format(dat$DateTime, "%H%M")), 
                               c(0, 600, 2000, 2359), 
                  labels=c("00:00-06:00", "06:00-20:00", "20:00-23:59"))

tab <- table(dat$Source, dat$bucket)
tab[tab>0] <- 1 # make it either 1 or 0 vs the summing table wld normally do

tab

##             00:00-06:00 06:00-20:00 20:00-23:59
##   10.0.0.10           0           1           0
##   10.0.0.11           0           1           1
##   10.0.0.19           1           0           0
##   10.0.0.6            0           1           0
```

You can convert the `table` to `data.frame` if need be and re-order the columns as needed, too.

Comment: It works!. Thank you very much! So it was using labels thought it was break.